# Featured Image on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a little problem... when I want to show the featured image on my posts, the chosen size isn't working (the photo is shown in it's own size). And I want the featured Image to be shown in the same width as the post total width but I have no clue!

This is the code I'm using in the PHP section

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); set_post_thumbnail_size(640, 205);
```

My question is... where do I have to put this code?

```
<?php add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );?>
```

And what would be the css I have to use to show it in the same width as the post total width?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the php code `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` on `functions.php` under the theme directory.

WordPress cutting thumbnails while uploading the file, so you have to enable the feature first then upload the image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what do you mean with "under the theme directory"?

Comment: @Dani like `themes/your-theme/functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

Put this code `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` in function.php file

Answer (score 0):

Select Post option,at right side bar corner,you will find the option as Featured images changes and updates,select and update the image which you require.

[image]

Else try with this Code format:
the_post_thumbnail();
set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50);`add_image_size( 'single-post-thumbnail', 590, 180 );