# Wp admin: not able to upload & view featured Images

Tags: php, wordpress, image, wp-admin

WordPress helps to manage blog-content and images. But in `wp-admin`, when I try to view **Featured Image** from Media Library, it just keeps loading... as shown below:

[image: img1]

And when I upload a new image, it gets uploaded but it isn't shown under **Featured Image** tab and even not on Blog. So neither, a new image gets uploaded nor old images are visible!

How to resolve the issue, to upload an image as featured image in "Wordpress".

Note: gone through [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080648/featured-image-on-wordpress), but it talks about image size.

Comment: Are you saving this thumbnail after posting it  ?

Comment: nope... I am just trying to upload an image...

Comment: Are you using https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_wp_post_thumbnail_html ?

Comment: Can you upload on the _media_ page? Is there a JS error in the console? Can you turn off all plugins, set a default theme does it still happen?

Comment: And I think you should consider looking into https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media that will giv you some clear idea on it.

Comment: let me know, if you still need my help. and do not forget to tag my name when replying me.

Comment: in your previous comment when you have said you are looking into it, I did not got notification for that, that is why I thought to remind you.